# Function to add DIV Class?

Tags: php

I'm building a WordPress options panel.

In my options panel I added the following, this creates a Yes/No dropdown menu asking whether or not the user wants to display breacrumbs - **I want to be able to hide (or simply not call) the breadcrumbs when a user selects no**:

```
array( "name" => "Display breadcrumbs on post pages?",
    "desc" => "Choose whether or not to display breadcrumbs, that is, the post trail.",
    "id" => $shortname."_breadcrumbs",
    "type" => "select",
    "options" => array("Yes", "No"),
    "std" => "Yes"),
```

Normally I would use something like this to call the above function:

```
<?php echo get_option('to_breadcrumbs'); ?>
```

But breadcrumbs have their own function, and I call them like so:

```
<?php if (function_exists('dimox_breadcrumbs')) dimox_breadcrumbs(); ?>
```

**One possible solution that could be applied in other uses would be to add a div class with the hide property around the function I am calling when "No" is selected.  Any help?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just check the options before calling `dimox_breadcrumbs()` like so:

```
<?php
    // Check if the user wants breadcrumbs, default to "Yes" if no option set
    if(strcmp(get_option("to_breadcrumbs", "Yes"), "Yes") == 0){
         if (function_exists('dimox_breadcrumbs')) {
             dimox_breadcrumbs();
         }
    }
?>
```